# Output table results as soon as they become available

Tags: evaluation, list-manipulation, result-accumulation

I'm using `Table[]` to repeat computations for a range of parameter values and every single value takes about 10 minutes. Is there a way to have Mathematica output the result of single computations as soon as it finishes rather than waiting for the whole operation to complete before I'm any wiser?

Consider this simple example.

```
Table[Pause[n^2] n^2, {n, 3}]
```

Is there a way to see the results 1, 4 and 9 after 1, 4 and 9 seconds, respectively, rather than having to wait the full 14 seconds?

Comment: Would `Table[Pause[n^2]; Print[n^2]; n^2, {n, 3}]` work for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic)? For example:

```
Dynamic[x]
Table[Pause[n^2];x=n^2,{n,3}]
```

Comment: Very useful to prevent a spam of outputs to be printed (if there are many to be done).

Answer (score 2):

I would put a print statement inside the table. Like:

```
Table[Pause[n^2]; x = n^2; Print[x]; x, {n, 3}]
```

In the above code, only `x`, i.e., the value which is output (has no `;` after it) goes to the table.